# How to access a functions result inside extension.ts? VS Code Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to write a VS Code Extension that displays simple metrics. This is my first time creating my own VS Code Extension and I've found the docs to be very unintuitive.

I want the extension to look for a specific file in a codebase and look for a specific function inside that file. Basically, I need to access that function's results inside extension.ts to be able to manipulate that data.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Any guidance would be extremely helpful.

Thank you,

Andy.